# how to dynamically get icon of the files using file extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is there any way to dynamically get the icon of the files using its extensions in Sharepoint SPFX?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SP.Web.mapToIcon method to map a file name to an icon. To use it from SPFx, you would make a REST API call to `/_api/web/maptoicon(filename, progid, size)`.

An example call would be `/_api/web/maptoicon(filename='filename.pdf', progid='', size='0')`.

Here are some additional resources that may help you.

[SP.Web.mapToIcon Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245123(v=office.15))

[Getting the default document icon using Office 365 SharePoint REST API](https://davidlozzi.com/2017/03/21/getting-the-default-document-icon-using-office-365-sharepoint-rest-api/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use approaches like `SP.Web.mapToIcon` as Rob says (as a general rule, you should always listen to what Rob says!), but if you simply want to render a file icon, you can use the PnP React Reusable Controls; There is a [FileTypeIcon control](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/blob/master/docs/documentation/docs/controls/FileTypeIcon.md) which does all the hard work for you.

After you install the control in your SPFx project (using `npm install @pnp/spfx-controls-react --save --save-exact`)

In your code, you need to import the control:

```
import { FileTypeIcon, ApplicationType, IconType, ImageSize } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/FileTypeIcon";
```

And then place the controls where you'd like to display them, passing the filename as a parameter:

```
/* Showing the icons font */
<FileTypeIcon type={IconType.font} path="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/documents/filename.docx" />
<FileTypeIcon type={IconType.font} path="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/documents/filename.xslx" />

/* Showing the icon image */
<FileTypeIcon type={IconType.image} path="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/documents/filename.docx" />

/* Icon image allows three different sizes */
<FileTypeIcon type={IconType.image} size={ImageSize.small} application={ApplicationType.Excel} />
<FileTypeIcon type={IconType.image} size={ImageSize.medium} application={ApplicationType.Excel} />
<FileTypeIcon type={IconType.image} size={ImageSize.large} application={ApplicationType.Excel} />
```

For more information, take a look at https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/FileTypeIcon/

I hope this helps?